# IIS is not installing in windows Home Basic

Tags: iis

I try to install iis in my windows home basic when i try to select features of iis only few displayed.And I try to install iis but it is not installed.Pls anyone help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the limitations of Home Basic, you will be unable to install all of the components within IIS, which explains why some of the features fail to appear. However, you could try downloading IIS Express, which is a lightweight version of IIS.

The following link provides a brief overview, comparing IIS and IIS Express:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview